# what is absolute url of an image for showing as webView(loadHTMLString) in objective c

Tags: iphone, xcode

i am new in objective c. i want to show an image (this image is in resources->images->a.png). Now i want to show it as `loadHTMLString` formate. so what will be the image path?  i have used "images\a.png" as src; but does not show the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] baseURLWithPrefix:@"file:"]];
```

that should work for you, provided your htmlString contain reference to your image similar to:

```
<img src=\"a.png\"/>
```

Comment: But i am using <table><tr><td>.... html formate and now want to add this image, so <img src="?" will be?

Comment: but i am using like  <img src=\"images/a.png\" />  but does not work.

Comment: @user913595, omit images/ and it will work! it works this way in two my apps.

Comment: but it does not work in my app.  just a.png image on resources->images folder and i have tried by two ways like src=\"images/a.png\and also src=\"a.png\".

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have got the answer:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```